# SwiftUI - Custom transition animation to replicate iOS standard

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui, navigation, state

I have a UI which is state driven i.e. we transition from one view to the next by changing states rather than using a navigation stack. I'm trying to replicate Apple's navigation animations (i.e. slide in/out) however am coming unstuck. The issue is that the animation direction will vary depending on whether we are navigating forwards or backwards.

As the project is very large, I've created a simple demo app to illustrate my problem. It consists of 3 views: initial, login and details. Here is the setup:

```
// Controls which view is active
enum ViewState: Int {
    case initial = 1
    case login
    case details
}

// Declares navigation direction
enum NavigationDirection {
    case forward
    case back
}

// Root view model  
class ContentViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var viewState: ViewState = .initial
    @Published var fromView: ViewState = .initial
    @Published var navigationDirection: NavigationDirection = .forward
    
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    init() {
        setupNavigationDirection()
    }
    
    func setState(_ state: ViewState) {
        viewState = state
    }
    
    private func setupNavigationDirection() {
        $viewState
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .sink { [weak self] state in
                guard let self = self else { return }
                if self.fromView.rawValue > state.rawValue {
                    self.navigationDirection = .back
                } else {
                    self.navigationDirection = .forward
                }
                print(self.navigationDirection)
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}

// Main root view
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel: ContentViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Title that remains in place")
            
            Spacer()
            
            switch viewModel.viewState {
            case .initial:
                initialView
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                    .animation(.default)
                    .transition(.move(edge: viewModel.navigationDirection == .forward ? .leading : .trailing))
                    .onAppear {
                        viewModel.fromView = .initial
                    }
            case .login:
                LoginView(viewModel: viewModel)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                    .animation(.default)
                    .transition(.move(edge: viewModel.navigationDirection == .forward ? .trailing : .leading))
                    .onAppear {
                        viewModel.fromView = .login
                    }
            case .details:
                DetailsView(viewModel: viewModel)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                    .animation(.default)
                    .transition(.move(edge: viewModel.navigationDirection == .forward ? .trailing : .leading))
                    .onAppear {
                        viewModel.fromView = .details
                    }
            }
        }

    }
    
    private var initialView: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 10) {
            Text("First View")
            
            ButtonView(contentViewModel: viewModel,
                       viewModel: .init(buttonType: .forward, stateChange: .login))
        }
    }
}

// Login view
struct LoginView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel: ContentViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 10) {
            Text("Login View")
            
            ButtonView(contentViewModel: viewModel,
                       viewModel: .init(buttonType: .forward, stateChange: .details))
            
            ButtonView(contentViewModel: viewModel,
                       viewModel: .init(buttonType: .back, stateChange: .initial))
        }
    }
}

// Details View
struct DetailsView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel: ContentViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 10) {
            Text("Details View")
 
            ButtonView(contentViewModel: viewModel,
                       viewModel: .init(buttonType: .back, stateChange: .login))
        }
    }
}

// Button type enum
enum ButtonType {
    case back
    case forward
    
    var backgroundColor: Color {
        switch self {
        case .back:
            return .red
        case .forward:
            return .blue
        }
    }
    
    var label: String {
        switch self {
        case .back:
            return "Back"
        case .forward:
            return "Forward"
        }
    }
}

// View model for ButtonView
class ButtonViewModel: ObservableObject {
    let buttonType: ButtonType
    let stateChange: ViewState
    
    init(buttonType: ButtonType, stateChange: ViewState) {
        self.buttonType = buttonType
        self.stateChange = stateChange
    }
}

// ButtonView
struct ButtonView: View {
    @ObservedObject var contentViewModel: ContentViewModel
    @StateObject var viewModel: ButtonViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            contentViewModel.setState(viewModel.stateChange)
        } label: {
            Text(viewModel.buttonType.label)
        }
        .padding()
        .background(viewModel.buttonType.backgroundColor)
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .cornerRadius(8)
    }
}
```

So, I'm tracking the navigation direction in the `ContentViewModel` via a Combine subscription to `viewState` and utilising the Int hierarchy from the ViewState enum. This tracking is working fine. But then I need to use this information to control the animation direction of each view.

The result I want is:

- when tapping on 'next' from initialView : initialView moves out to .leading and loginView comes in from .trailing
- when tapping on 'back' from LoginView : LoginView moves out to .trailing, initialView moves in from .leading
- when tapping 'next' from LoginView, LoginView moves out to .leading, and DetailsView moves in from .trailing.
- when tapping 'back' from DetailsView: DetailsView moves out to .trailing, and LoginView moves in from .leading

So here, LoginView needs to move out to different edges depending on the current navigation direction. However, I am at a loss as to how to control the animations to this degree.

My approach above is to have the edge dependent on `navigationDirection`. But this is obviously flawed as the view get initialised with the correct navigation direction but then does not adapt when `navigationDirection` is changed.

Wondering if there is a better, more obvious approach that I'm missing here.

Comment: We have a similar setup in our SwiftUI app with a coordinator and using custom push/pop transitions. Have you had any luck getting this working? Our current solution was working fine prior to iOS 16, but seems to have broken now. Currently trying to troubleshoot why exactly, but haven't had much luck yet.

Comment: Encountering the exact same issue. Any solutions as yet? @AllanPoole